# Wall-clock timer (performance counter) in numba's nopython mode

Tags: python, macos, ctypes, numba, cffi

I have a long-running numerical routine written with numba, using it's nopython mode. Because it's nopython, I cannot use `KeyboardInterrupt` to stop it, nor do I get any feedback on it's progress while it's running. Thus, I would like to periodically interrupt the routine to drop back into python. I would like to use wall-clock time to determine at what point to stop. Is there any such timer available that I could use from numba's nopython mode? I guess one could use numba's `ctypes` or `cffi` support to call some function from a suitable library. Is there such a function in the python binary or another standard library on OS X?